# Unable to use Excel as Database in Automation Anywhere 10

Tags: excel, automation, automationanywhere

I am trying to use Excel as Database in Automation Anywhere 10. Following is my code

```
Connect to "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0",Data Source = C:\Users\myuser\Documents\demo.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 10.0 Xml;HDR=YES";"Session:"session1"
Execute SQL statement:'Select * from [Sheet1]$'
```

But it is showing the following error,

```
Provider cannot be found. It may not properly installed.
```

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
dim cn as object, cnstr as string, rs as object

set cn = createobject("adodb.connection")
cnstr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0,Data Source=C:\Users\myuser\Documents\demo.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 10.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";Session:""session1"""
set rs = cn.Execute("Select * from [Sheet1]$")
```

some version EXCEL use `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` instead of `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you can check

1. You may not have the database engine actually installed for the Office suite. I would check this first especially if you've not been able to connect before. Here is a [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920). This requires Access be installed, I think.
2. You may also try `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` or `Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;HDR=YES";` as I do not think you need to the `XML` in `Excel 10.0 XML`.
3. I have two additional notes for when you get it working:

   - You need to reference your table name like so `[$vSheetName$$]` with the $ inside the brackets. Two dollar signs like so if you're inputting a variable
   - It is a best practice to wrap your headers in ticks [ ` ] seen between the brackets. With AA, if any header has spaces, this is the only way to parse it

Answer (score 0):

Your query syntax is incorrect.

Try using the following syntax instead:

```
Select * from [Sheet1$]
```